# C#. How to transform 1D array to 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays

I know this has been asked numerous times before, but I could not find what specifically I 'm looking for.
I'm currently trying to write c# method that displays int array as vertical bars on console. My idea is to transform 1D array into 2D.
if `input = {2, 1, 3}`; Output should look like:

```
{{0, 0, 1},
 {1, 0, 1},
 {1, 1, 1}}
```

Then I could replace 1 and 0 by character of my choice to display the image on the console.
So far my method looks like this:

```
    public static void DrawGraph()
    {
         int[] randomArray = new int[3]{ 2, 1, 3 };
         int[,] graphMap = new int[3, 3];

             for(int i = 0; i < graphMap.GetLength(0); i++)
             {
                for(int j = 0; j < graphMap.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    graphMap[i, j] = randomArray[j];
                    Console.Write(graphMap[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
             }
    }
```

And it produces output:

```
2 1 3
2 1 3
2 1 3
```

Comment: For first value in array 2, why in 2d array 0,1,1 not 1,0,1 or 1, 1, 0?

Comment: I've read this several times, and I'm afraid I can't see the link between your input and your output.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Why would the `{2, 1, 3}` input result in `{{0, 0, 1},
 {1, 0, 1},
 {1, 1, 1}}` as output?  Are you looking to make the columns of the 2D array sum up to the 1D array?

Comment: in the second for loop - change `graphMap[i, j]=randomArray[j];` to `graphMap[i, j]=1`

Comment: I suspect the OP is confused about the difference between a 1d/2d image with a 1d/2d array...  Also if the number of elements in graphMap exceeds the elements in randomArray, that code will bomb with an IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: @Nuclear_Man_D That would just set all the values in the 2D array to 1.

Comment: @AdrianWragg I believe each integer in the original array specifies how many `1`:s are found vertically bottom-up in the resulting array. Think of it as a bar graph with 1:s as the bars.

Comment: If you do `graphMap[i, j] = (3-i) > randomArray[j] ? 0 : 1;` that will give you the output you expect.  But that only works for this specific example we'd need more info to give you a more general solution, specifically it seems like the first dimension of the 2D array should be the max value in the 1D array maybe.

Comment: Why are you storing the values into `graphMap[i, j]`, looks a waste memory/cpu to me

Comment: Yes, the output does not have to be integer array. Replace 1 with "#" and  0 with " ". Idea is to produce the column as high, as current value in the 1dArray. For example value 1 in 1dArray puts one # and 2 spaces; value 2  - 2 #'es an 1 space etc.  And, yes I'm aware of the IndexOutOfRangeException if number of elements in graphMap exceeds the elements in randomArray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the 2D array is only relevant as a tool to help you print, you can leave it out completely.

```
private static readonly char GraphBackgroundChar = '0';
private static readonly char GraphBarChar = '1';

void Main()
{
    int[] input = {4, 1, 6, 2};
    int graphHeight = input.Max(); // using System.Linq;

    for (int currentHeight = graphHeight - 1; currentHeight >= 0; currentHeight--)
    {
        OutputLayer(input, currentHeight);
    }
}

private static void OutputLayer(int[] input, int currentLevel)
{
    foreach (int value in input)
    {
        // We're currently printing the vertical level `currentLevel`.
        // Is this value's bar high enough to be shown on this height?
        char c = currentLevel >= value
            ? GraphBackgroundChar
            : GraphBarChar;
        Console.Write(c);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

What this basically does is it finds the "highest bar" from the input, then loops through each vertical level top-to-bottom, printing `GraphBarChar` each time a graph bar in `input` is visible at the current height.

Some samples:

input = {2, 1, 3};

```
001
101
111
```

input = {2, 4, 1, 0, 3};

```
01000
01001
11001
11101
```

If your targeted platforms support box-drawing characters in the terminal emulators, you could use the following characters for some pretty convincing bar graphs:

```
private static readonly char GraphBackgroundChar = '░';
private static readonly char GraphBarChar = '█';
```

input = {2, 1, 3};

```
░░█
█░█
███
```

input = {2, 4, 1, 0, 3};

```
░█░░░
░█░░█
██░░█
███░█
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @TomasSmilgius I'm glad I could help! I updated the for loop in my answer to clarify what's happening.

Comment: By the way, @TomasSmilgius, you can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark at the top left of the answer.

Comment: That also helped a lot. This will be used for the program to display sorting algorithms on the console .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better function than the one given already,

```
static void DrawGraph(int[] array)
{
    int maxElementValue = 0;
    foreach (int i in array)
    {
        if (i > maxElementValue) maxElementValue = i;
    }

    for (int rowIndex= 0; rowIndex < maxElementValue; ++rowIndex)
    {
        foreach (int i in array)
        {
            Console.Write((i < rowIndex - columnIndex ? 0 : 1) + " ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

It works as desired.